# Cumulative Distribution Function of the skewed generalized error distribution

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

I´m trying to calculate the cumulative distribution function of the skewed generalized error distribution with the probability density function:

[image]

where u = y - m.
From Theodossiou in ([https://www.mfsociety.org/modules/modDashboard/uploadFiles/journals/MJ~0~p1a4fjq38m1k2p45t6481fob7rp4.pdf](https://www.mfsociety.org/modules/modDashboard/uploadFiles/journals/MJ%7E0%7Ep1a4fjq38m1k2p45t6481fob7rp4.pdf)). I tried some calculations but they are not worth mentioning.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jo. What is your question?

Comment: Hey whuber, my question ist what the cdf of this pdf is.

Comment: Consider a change of variable.

Comment: You will need an incomplete Gamma function for this calculation: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution.  The derivation begins with the substitution (change of variable) (A3) in your reference.  Otherwise, consider numerical integration.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Applying the general recommendations for recognizing distributions set out at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/332844/919, we see (without any calculation) that up to a change of scale (differing according to whether $u$ is positive or negative), these densities are proportional to $\exp(-|u|^k).$

The absolute value and the presence of the signum ("sign of") function suggest breaking the integration of the density into positive and negative regions (and reversing the sign of $u$ on the negative region).  **This reduces the question to the following:**

> Evaluate $\int_0^u \exp(-t^k)\mathrm dt$ for $u \gt 0.$

The most direct and obvious route to simplification is to **make $z = t^k$ the variable of integration.**  This is expedited by using the logarithmic differential $\mathrm dz/z = \mathrm d(t^k)/t^k = k\,\mathrm dt/t$ (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185709/919):

$$\exp\left(-t^k\right)\mathrm dt = \exp\left(-t^k\right)\ t \frac{\mathrm dt}{t} = \frac{1}{k}\exp(-z)\ z^{1/k}\frac{\mathrm dz}{z}.$$

Its integral (without the factor of $1/k$) defines the [lower incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) with shape parameter $1/k,$ often written $\gamma.$  Thus, since the upper limit of the integral is $z^{1/k} = t = u,$ we must evaluate this integral from $z = 0$ to $z = u^k:$

> $$\int_0^u \exp\left(-t^k\right)\mathrm dt = \frac{1}{k}\gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}, u^k\right).$$

(Evidently $k$ must be positive.)  The rest is straightforward algebra.

As far as implementing $\gamma$ goes, it's available in most (if not all) statistical computing platforms because when $X$ has a $\Gamma(1/k)$ distribution and $x \gt 0,$

$$\Gamma(1/k)\Pr(X\le x) = \int_0^x z^{1/k}\exp(-z)\frac{\mathrm dz}{z} = \gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}, x\right).$$

Compute the factors on the left to obtain the value of $\gamma.$

---

**As a check and a working example,** in `R` we may numerically integrate $\exp(-t^k)$

```R
f <- Vectorize(function(u, k) {integrate(\(t) exp(-t^k), 0, u)$value}, "u")
```

and compare that to this solution where $\Gamma$ is implemented with `lgamma` (the logarithm of the Gamma function, used to avoid numeric overflows for small $k$) and $\Pr(X\le x)$ is implemented with `pgamma`:

```R
g <- function(u, k) exp(-log(k) + lgamma(1/k) + pgamma(u^k, 1/k, log.p = TRUE))
```

Graphs of the functions `f` and `g` coincide (at least for non-extreme values of $k;$ for very small values the numeric integration becomes problematic).