Special case of parameters in the Gamma distribution function?
I am currently working with images using Voronoi tessellations and evaluating the distribution of the corresponding cell areas. These areas are said to be gamma-distributed, derived from the 1D case.
The version of the Gamma distribution (pdf) on Wikipedia has a shape parameter (alpha) and a rate parameter (beta).
See here --> Wikipedia version of the Gamma distribution
I am confused by a paper (and some other papers referencing this one). Here, a different version is said to be "the Gamma function".
See here--> Gamma distribution in the paper, page 436
My question now is:
Can someone explain to me in relatively simple terms if this is a special case of a Gamma distribution and/or how both versions relate to each other?
Thank you.

Closely related, and likely helpful, are https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49700 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332797 (not about Gammas, but showing how to solve a similar problem)

Using the shape/rate parameterization on Wikipedia, the pdf of a Gamma($\alpha, \beta$) random variable $X$ is given for $x>0$ by
$$
f(x) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma (\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\beta x}, x> 0,
$$
and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. The version in the linked paper reads for $x>0$
$$
H(x;c) = \frac{c}{\Gamma(c)}(cx)^{c-1}\mathrm{e}^{-cx}
$$
and 0 otherwise. If you select $\alpha = c$ and $\beta = c$ for some $c > 0$, then the first specification becomes
$$
f(x) = \frac{c^{c}}{\Gamma(c)}x^{c-1}\mathrm{e}^{-cx} = \frac{c}{\Gamma(c)}(cx)^{c-1}\mathrm{e}^{-cx},
$$
which is the same as in the paper. So the version used in the paper is a specific case of the Gamma distribution with shape and rate set to be equal to each other.
